# Why aren't CirclePoints[] evenly distributed?

Tags: graphics, histograms

If you run something like this;

```
num = 1000;
circlepoints = CirclePoints[num];
angles = Table[ArcTan[circlepoints[[i, 2]]/circlepoints[[i, 1]]], {i, 1, num, 1}];
angles = angles + 1.5;
Histogram[angles, Automatic, Probability]
```

I get a histogram which looks a bit strange...

[image: Histogram plot with drooping probability at either end]

How can we have angles which exceed 3 radians and are smaller than 0?

The circle looks round...

[image: plot of a the points obtained from CirclePoints]

The first line of the documentation for `CirclePoints` states:

> gives the positions of $n$ points equally spaced around the unit circle.

Comment: [`ArcTan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html) is defined from `[-Pi/2, Pi/2]` but you're only adding on `1.5`

Comment: Sorry, but I think the issue is silly (the question but not the questioner).  Prior to adding 1.5 to `angles` (or even after for that matter) one can just execute `Differences[angles]` and see that all values are $\pi/500$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I's say a combination of your code not using an accurate value for `Pi/2` and of the automatic binning for `Histogram`. See the following instead, which uses your definition of `circlepoints`:

```
angles = ArcTan[#2/#1] + Pi/2 & @@@ circlepoints;
With[{n = 20}, 
  Histogram[%, {Pi/n}, Ticks -> {Subdivide[0, Pi, n], Automatic}]
]
```

[image: flat histogram]

Comment: You can also just use `ArcTan` with its two-argument form to get something on the `[-Pi, Pi]` range where you can really see the even-ness

Comment: @b3m2a1 Good point, thank you! I saw your answer that covers that point, so I'll leave this as-is for the sake of variety.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way to see the even-ness:

```
num = 1000;
circlepoints = CirclePoints[num];
angles2 = ArcTan[circlepoints[[All, 1]], circlepoints[[All, 2]]];
angles2 // Differences // DeleteDuplicates

{π/500, -((999 π)/500)}
```

You can see that except for when you wrap around to `2 Pi` everything has a constant difference in angle

Comment: Because there really is no random selection involved (and hence a histogram is at best an indirect approach), what you show is exactly the way to show the exact evenness.

Comment: @JimB yeah for `SpherePoints` a histogram would be more useful, but not for this